# Mysql add duplicate varchar

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = 'insert into forum_post(user, text, topic, categ) values ("'.$mysql->real_escape($_POST['user']).'","'.$mysql->real_escape($_POST['text']).'","'.$mysql->real_escape($_POST['title']).'","'.$mysql->real_escape($_POST['categ']).'")';
$mysql->query($sql);
$sql = 'insert into forum_topic(name, user, categ) values ("'.$mysql->real_escape($_POST['title']).'","'.$mysql->real_escape($_POST['user']).'","'.$mysql->real_escape($_POST['categ']).'")';
$mysql->query($sql);
```

I'm trying to add a new line into forum_topic which holds the same NAME(which is not a primary or unique key). But it won't add, and I have no idea why. Forum_post works.

```
|------
|Column|Type|Null|Default
|------
|//**id**//|int(10)|No|
|**name**|varchar(16)|No|
|user|varchar(32)|No|
|timestamp|datetime|No|CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
|categ|varchar(16)|No|
|posts|int(10)|Yes|NULL
== Dumping data for table forum_topic

|19|asd|test34|2015-03-26 20:59:12|discuss|NULL
|4|test|test|0000-00-00 00:00:00|introductions|0
|5|test1|test|0000-00-00 00:00:00|introductions|0
```

Those are the columns. Those being: id(primary and AI), name(is the problem), user, timestamp, category, number_of_posts.
I'm trying to add the name "asd" with the categ of "introductions". But every time I do it, it adds the data in forum_post and won't even budge forum_topic. Any other value works. If I were to put something different of "asd","test","test1" at name it would work.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.2.7.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Mar 26, 2015 at 09:25 PM
-- Server version: 5.6.20
-- PHP Version: 5.5.15

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `mangacreator_main`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `forum_topic`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forum_topic` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `categ` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `posts` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=57 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `forum_topic`
--

INSERT INTO `forum_topic` (`id`, `name`, `user`, `timestamp`, `categ`,  `posts`) VALUES
(4, 'test', 'test', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'introductions', 0),
(5, 'test1', 'test', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'introductions', 0),
(19, 'asd', 'test34', '2015-03-26 20:59:12', 'discuss', NULL);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `forum_topic`
--
ALTER TABLE `forum_topic`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`), ADD FULLTEXT KEY  `name_2` (`name`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `forum_topic`
--
ALTER TABLE `forum_topic`
MODIFY `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=57;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

And this is the actual one... I may have put too much in there...

```
CREATE TABLE `forum_topic` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
 `user` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `categ` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
 `posts` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `name_2` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=57 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Never did select name as a unique key... And I can't choose or discard it be it so.

Comment: You need to add some error checking to your code and you'll get your answer.

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information.

Comment: I have no idea what should I do. When doing trigger_error I get an error on the same line with it. Trying to see if my code is bad is not working, tried adding a 'qqq' and it works perfectly.

Comment: Can you show us the actual table creation query?

Comment: It is right there in the `ALTER TABLE` statement. The `ADD UNIQUE KEY name (name),` will prevent duplicate entries. Error checking would have revealed this.

Comment: But it won't let me change it... I haven't chose the unique thing... Is it a special characteristic to varchar?

Comment: No, you would have to perform another alter table to drop the key.

Comment: It works... I'm such a dumb person...Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can drop the index on your name field by running the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE DROP INDEX `name` ON `forum_topic`;
```